# Inno Setup: How to change LicenseFile text?

Tags: inno-setup

I have a single license.txt file. I use it for all of my applications.

```
[Setup]
LicenseFile=license.txt
```

I want my user to see a title *"{#MyAppName} License Agreement"* at the beginning of the license agreement text. But I don't want to change `license.txt` file content.

Is there any Inno Setup code way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, to change the fist line of license, you can do:

```pascal
[Code]

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  WizardForm.LicenseMemo.Lines[0] := '{#MyAppName} License Agreement';
  WizardForm.LicenseMemo.SelStart := 0;
end;
```

[image]

---

Another way is to use [Inno Setup preprocessor](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/) to generate a modified license file out of your template file.

Comment: That's great. Thank you